# Deleting Rows using Update Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help in deleting rows from by table with an Update statement were there are characters other than the numbers. I am using MS Access but using their SQL view.I need to remove "words go here" and "hello how are you". Please see below

```
999999   45.72
999999   55.36
words go here
999999   411.12
Hello how are you
8888888   63.39
```

Comment: Which database are you using?  And btw, your title has nothing to do with your question....

Comment: Use `DELETE` to delete rows. `UPDATE` updates rows.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and follow the instructions.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server,` etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data suggest `LIKE` predicate :

```
where col not like '%[a-z]%';
```

Comment: `Lower (col)` else you will end up deleting valid rows.